# How to get s3distcp to merge with newlines

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr

I have many millions of small one line s3 files that I'm looking to merge together.  I have the s3distcp syntax down, however, I've discovered that after merging the files no newlines are contained in the merged set.

I was wondering if s3distcp includes any option to force a newline in, or is there another way to accomplish this without modifying the source files directly (or copying them and doing the same)

Comment: Looks like you need to add new line to the one line file itself.  Isn't that an option?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid that and get that "for free" from s3distcp directly, but doesn't sound like I can avoid that unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

If your text files begin/end with a unique sequence of characters, you can first merge them into a single file with `s3distcp` (I did this by by setting `--targetSize` to a very large number), then use `sed` with Hadoop streaming to add in the new lines; in the following example, each file contains a single json (the filenames all begin with `0`), and the `sed` command inserts a newline between each instance of `}{`:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs:///tmpoutputfolder/
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs:///finaloutputfolder/
hadoop jar lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar \
               --src s3://inputfolder \
               --dest hdfs:///tmpoutputfolder \
               --targetSize 1000000000 \
               --groupBy ".*(0).*"
hadoop jar /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \
               -D mapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
               --input hdfs:///tmpoutputfolder \
               --output hdfs:///finaloutputfolder \
               --mapper /bin/cat \
               --reducer '/bin/sed "s/}{/}\n{/g"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same probrem and `sed` command breaks folder structures.
s3distcp is just MapReduce program.
So other way is to write a MapReduce program which is merging and add new line, more behavier you like.

Or you can search such a MapReduce program from internet, GitHub repository,  I created one of them github.com/ksmaxeed/s3distcp.